# cameracalibrator.py GUI does not start

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to get the camera parameters for my webcam. I'm using the uvc_cam package with camera_calibration package. The commands I use to start are as follows:

`

> roscore

> rosrun uvc_camera camera_node

> rosrun camera_calibration camacalibrator.py --size 10x7 --square 0.022 image:/usb_cam/image_raw camera:=/
> Waiting for service //set_camera_info ...
> OK`

At this point, nothing happens. Does anyone have a rough idea what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31967/cameracalibrator.py-gui-does-not-start/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is two things you should try :

First : I see that you type image:/usb_cam but It should be for remapping   image:=/usb_cam with the "=" !

Then I did not see what you have set for your camera since it seems that you have paste the answer of you terminal right after you camera:=/ command

So to complete your command line do a rostopic list as follow

```
vvittori@delos:~/ros_workspace/stereo_robust_matching$ rostopic list
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/cameraUEYE_node/parameter_descriptions
/cameraUEYE_node/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

and then set the command line as follow (in my exemple /camera/image_raw is my image and /camera is my camera name )

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera
```

So for you it should be I gess

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 10x7 --square 0.022  image:=/usb_cam/image_raw camera:=/usb_cam
```

Regards

V.v

---

Originally posted by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) with karma: 91 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the same problem, although mine is when I try to calibrate 2 PGR Chameleon cameras. I am sure I am remapping correctly, as when I open the rxgraph it shows proper connections. However, the GUI just wont pop up. Following is the code that I have used for the stereo calibration:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 10x6 --square 0.078 right:=/stereo/right/pgr_camera/image_raw left:=/stereo/left/pgr_camera/image_raw right_camera:=/stereo/right/pgr_camera left_camera:=/stereo/left/pgr_camera
Waiting for service /stereo/left/pgr_camera/set_camera_info ...
OK
Waiting for service /stereo/right/pgr_camera/set_camera_info ...
OK
```

Next, I tried calibrating a single camera in the mono-mode, and although the GUI pops up, I cannot get the calibration lines displayed on my Checkerboard.
This is the command that I have used to run in the mono-mode:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x5 --square 0.078 image:=/stereo/left/pgr_camera/image_raw cara:=/stereo/left/pgr_camera
Waiting for service /stereo/left/pgr_camera/set_camera_info ...
OK
```

---

Originally posted by [amittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2934/amittal/) with karma: 11 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2934/amittal/) on 2012-07-27**:
ok the gui has booted up!!! I added the --approximate=0.1 parameter to the rosrun